# Installation TYPO3 version 12.4

Tags: typo3-12.x

I am trying to install TYPO3 version 12.4. And I have an error:

Script typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure handling event typo3-cms-scripts returned with error code 1
The @typo3-cms-scripts script was called via post-autoload-dump.

I updated Composer, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. The working command line (in the typo3 project directory) should be

```
./vendor/bin/typo3 install:fixfolderstructure
```

(and not ./vendor/bin/typo3cms...). The corresponding entry in the 'composer.json' file in the typo3 project directory was "typo3cms".

I solved it changing the corresponding entry in the file 'composer.json' to:

```
    "scripts":{
    "typo3-cms-scripts": [
        "typo3 install:fixfolderstructure"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "@typo3-cms-scripts"
    ]
}
```

You can find more information on typo3 console commands in the [command reference of the package helhum/typo3-console](https://docs.typo3.org/p/helhum/typo3-console/main/en-us/CommandReference/Index.html)